# Split long SQL expression at delimiter

Tags: bash, split, sql

### Context

I'm trying to import a dump that have some  long lines (8k+ character) with SQL*Plus, so I face the error `SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters)`. This is a hard-coded limit and cannot be overcome.

### Expected solution

I would like to stream my input in bash and to split lines longer than the expected width on the last `,` (comma) character.

So I should have something like

```
cat my_dump.sql | *magic_command* | sqlplus system/oracle@xe
```

### Details

1. I know that newer version can accept lines up to 4999 characters but I still have lines longer (`grep '.\{5000\}' my_dump.sql | wc -l`)
2. It is not really feasible to update the dump by hand
3. I did try to use `tr` but this split every line wich I do not want
4. I did try to use `fmt` and `fold` but it does not seems to be possible to use a custom delimiter
5. I am currently looking on `sed` but I cannot seem to figure out a regexp that would "find the last match of `,` in the first 2500 characters if there is more than 2500 characters"

Comment: Are you sure that `,` can't also appear in literal strings - in which case appending newlines after them would alter the values inserted in tables? Also, are there lines with more that 2500 consecutive characters with no commas?

Comment: @fra-san interesting questions, for the commas in literal string they might exist but I do not want to handle this case. As for the "2500 consecutive characters with no commas" i'm pretty sure there is not, if there is and it discard the line I am okay with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
sed -re '/.{2500}/ s/.{,2500},/&\n/g'
```

Explanation:

- `/.{2500}/` if line contains 2500 characteres (or more) ...
- `s/.{,2500},/&\n/g` substitute up to 2500 char followed by a `,` adding a newline

I would not be surprised if this replaces some unreplaceble ","...

Comment: Oh thank you, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine something like this awk command would work:

```
awk 'length > 2499 {gsub(/.{0,2498},/, "&\n")} 1'
```

The regex allows for up to 2498 characters before a comma, (so 2499 including the comma), and inserts a newline after it. (I used 2499 since the error messages mentions that number.)

Comment: I might miss something but this does not seem to work `echo "this is a test, test, test, test, test" | awk 'length > 20 {gsub(/.{0,19},/, "&\n")} 1'`

Comment: @homer outputs `this is a test,`  `test, test, test,` `test` on separate lines for me

Comment: @muru, It also works for me but  (I can't say why )  if you replace 19 by 1900 it seems to block,